# ActionView::SyntaxErrorInTemplate in DiscussionsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and I'm stuck with this problem. I've looked at the other similar problems but did not find a solution that worked for me.
So its a discussion platform but any time i click to view a discussion i get an error:

> Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check

```
<div class="columns"> 
<div class="column is-8"> 
<h1 class="title is-2 has-text-grey discussion-title"><%= @discussion.title %></h1> <h3 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-grey-lighter">by <%= @discussion.user.username %> in <%= link_to @discussion.channel.channel, @discussion.channel %></h3> <div class="level"> <div class="level-left"></div> <div class="level-right"> <% if discussion_author(@discussion) %> <div class="buttons"> <%= link_to 'Edit Discussion', edit_discussion_path(@discussion), class:'button'%> <%= link_to 'Delete', discussion_path(@discussion), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Delete discussion?" }, class:'button' %> </div> <% end %> </div> </div> <div class="content"><%= markdown(@discussion.content) %></div> <h2 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-grey"><%= @discussion.replies.count %> Replies</h2> <div id="discussion-replies"> <%=# render @discussion.replies %> </div> <hr/> <h3 class="subtitle is-3 has-text-grey">Leave a reply</h3> <% if user_signed_in? %> <%=# render 'replies/form' %> <% else %> <p>To reply you need to <%= link_to 'login', new_user_session_path %>. Don't have an account? <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %> for one.</p> <% end %> </div> <%= render 'sidebar' %> </div>

 <div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-8">
    <h1 class="title is-2 has-text-grey discussion-title"><%= @discussion.title %></h1>
    <h3 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-grey-lighter">by <%= @discussion.user.username %> in <%= link_to @discussion.channel.channel, @discussion.channel %></h3>
    <div class="level">
      <div class="level-left"></div>
      <div class="level-right">
        <% if discussion_author(@discussion) %>
        <div class="buttons">
            <%= link_to 'Edit Discussion', edit_discussion_path(@discussion), class:'button'%>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', discussion_path(@discussion), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Delete discussion?" }, class:'button' %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"><%= markdown(@discussion.content) %></div>

    <h2 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-grey"><%= @discussion.replies.count %> Replies</h2>

    <div id="discussion-replies">
      <%= render @discussion.replies %>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <h3 class="subtitle is-3 has-text-grey">Leave a reply</h3>()
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= render 'replies/form' %>
    <% else %>
    <p>To reply you need to <%= link_to 'login', new_user_session_path %>. Don't have an account?
      <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %> for one.</p>
    <% end %>

  </div>

  <%= render 'sidebar' %>

</div>
```

Extracted source (around line #22):

expecting to move to show page when a post is selected

Comment: This is a syntax error:

    `<%=# ... %>`

should be

   `<%#= ... %>`

(Also you have this `</div>><hr />`)

Comment: @SebastianPalma Isn't it perfectly fine, since it tries to create comments ? So the line will not be executed.

Comment: What do you mean @YanaAgunSiswanto? `<%#= ... %>` won't execute what's inside `<% %>`.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work, just tested it on ruby's default erb library.

Comment: @Sebastian Palma i brought the # because i haven't started working on the reply/comment  section but is done and yet cant view it , and also the </div>><hr /> was a mistake thanks.